# how to copy value from one row(timestamp) to all the rows(timestamp) of a column in pyspark

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have pyspark dataframe like below

```
Name|ManagerName|Maxdateutc

ABC|XYZ|2021-12-21T23:59:59.0000000

PQR|BED|null

SUV|YTR|null
```

...and so on

I need output like below

```
Name|ManagerName|Maxdateutc

ABC|XYZ|2021-12-21 23:59:59.0000000

PQR|BED|2021-12-21 23:59:59.0000000

SUV|YTR|2021-12-21 23:59:59.0000000
```

Could you please tell me how to do this in pyspark

Comment: What did you try? Please update the question with the code that doesn't work for you. This improves the quality of the question and avoids downvotes.

Also do you have just 1 value in Maxdateutc as shown or there can be multiple values? Right now the question is not clear

Answer (score 0):

You can collect the first `non null` `Maxdateutc` value and use that to fill, for all `null` values.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

data = [("ABC", "XYZ", "2021-12-21T23:59:59.0000000",),
        ("PQR", "BED", None),
        ("SUV", "YTR", None), ]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ("Name", "ManagerName", "Maxdateutc",))

default_value = df.select("Maxdateutc").where("Maxdateutc is not null").head().Maxdateutc

df.withColumn("Maxdateutc", F.coalesce(F.col("Maxdateutc"), F.lit(default_value))).show(truncate=False)
```

### Output

```
+----+-----------+---------------------------+
|Name|ManagerName|Maxdateutc                 |
+----+-----------+---------------------------+
|ABC |XYZ        |2021-12-21T23:59:59.0000000|
|PQR |BED        |2021-12-21T23:59:59.0000000|
|SUV |YTR        |2021-12-21T23:59:59.0000000|
+----+-----------+---------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark=SparkSession.builder.appName("practise").getOrCreate()
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

data = [("ABC", "XYZ", "2021-12-21T23:59:59.0000000",),
        ("PQR", "BED", None),
        ("SUV", "YTR", None), ]
inp=spark.createDataFrame(data, ("Name", "ManagerName", "Maxdateutc",))
inp.show(5,0)

+----+-----------+---------------------------+
|Name|ManagerName|Maxdateutc                 |
+----+-----------+---------------------------+
|ABC |XYZ        |2021-12-21T23:59:59.0000000|
|PQR |BED        |null                       |
|SUV |YTR        |null                       |
+----+-----------+---------------------------+

inp=inp.withColumn("new_Maxdateutc", F.when(inp['Maxdateutc'] == F.lit('2021-12-21T23:59:59.0000000'),\
                                        F.lit('2021-12-21T23:59:59.0000000'))\
                   .otherwise('2021-12-21T23:59:59.0000000')).drop(inp['Maxdateutc'])
inp.show(5,0)

+----+-----------+---------------------------+
|Name|ManagerName|new_Maxdateutc             |
+----+-----------+---------------------------+
|ABC |XYZ        |2021-12-21T23:59:59.0000000|
|PQR |BED        |2021-12-21T23:59:59.0000000|
|SUV |YTR        |2021-12-21T23:59:59.0000000|
+----+-----------+---------------------------+
```